# Handling non JSON API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get a circulating supply number of a token and use the API to do a further calculation with it.

All I could find was people handling JSON outputs but this is just a plain output:
https://avascan.info/api/v1/supply?q=circulatingSupply

Anyone that can help me how I can fetch this amount and use it to further do calculations with?

Comment: What's the problem? If it isn't JSON then don't pass it through a JSON parser.

Comment: `Number.parseFloat()`

Comment: @Quentin I cant find anything on how to extract that plain value from the API, my problem isnt the JSON just that I can only find JSON examples handling API

Comment: @OmeD — How would you extract JSON from it? Figure that out, then look at the documentation for the object you do that on. Look for something that gives you text or raw data.

Comment: @OmeD with the `fetch` API you can call the `text` method on the response object to retrieve the raw data, then you can cast the value to a number with the [`Number` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which have a `text` method on it's response, for example:

```js
const BASE_URL = 'https://avascan.info/api/v1/supply?q=circulatingSupply';

async function getCirculatingSupply() {
  const response = await fetch(BASE_URL);
  const data = await response.text();
  return Number(data);
}

getCirculatingSupply().then(console.log);
```

Keep in mind that maybe you will have problems with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), as I had testing this API, so maybe you will need to use a proxy server like [cors-anywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere) to bypass this problem.